# Will Azure Service Bus connection survive Azure Service Fabric node shuffling?

Tags: messaging, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

I am using Azure Service Bus (ASB) Messaging as the [Message-oriented middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware) (MOM). Specifically, Topic and Subscriptions as a Pub-Sub solution.

I am using ASB within Azure Service Fabric (ASF) Cluster. ASF cluster management can shuffle the nodes which will kill the connections to ASB.

I wonder what will be the proper way to gracefully terminate the connections?

I am considering to have a Pub-Sub solution within the cluster down the road. That will solve it and other issues.

Please check this link to understand why I what to keep the connection alive:
"[Establishing a connection is an expensive operation that you can avoid by re-using the same factory and client objects for multiple operations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements) "

Comment: Make sure you have a look at this community package: https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections will not survive when a service instance/replica is moved from one node to another. You will need to implement a Service Fabric communication listener that will be invoked every time a service instance/replica is started and stopped.

Answer (score 0):

> ASF cluster management can shuffle the nodes which will might kill the connections to ASB.

It will, when service fabric move the services around the cluster, it will kill the process and start another instance of the service in other node, the MessagingFactory and the connections are isolated per process, even in case you use a shared a process, you would have to recreate these connections when the new instance comes up.

> For now, I can save the connection within the stateful service's reliable collection

I don't know what you mean with this, a connection is not like a bunch of data you store somewhere, it is like power cable connected to the main, it is connected or not.

> [Establishing a connection is an expensive operation that you can avoid by re-using the same factory and client objects for multiple operations.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients)

I think you misunderstood the idea on this topic.

Opening a connection when the service start is not expensive, expensive is opening and closing the connection on every iteration through the queue. 
If Your service move around the cluster that often, I think the connection time will be the least of your problems.

This rule is meant for scenarios where you don't keep the state between iterations, an example is a request to a web application that will process some data and put a message in a queue, if you had to open the connection on every request, this would slow down the process, in this case this rule applies, so you would keep an instance of the QueueSender with the connection open, so each consecutive request reuse the previous connection.